# _stdio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, macos, gcc, compilation

`

```
gcc *.c
In file included from get_next_line.h:16,
                 from get_next_line.c:13:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0/lib/gcc/current/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin20/12/include-fixed/stdio.h:78:10: fatal error: _stdio.h: No such file or directory
   78 | #include <_stdio.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

`

Hello, i got an issue when i try to compile on MAC os (i've just updated it to Ventura), it s like the path to my libraries are not the good one any more, any help on this please ?

Comment: How did you install GCC? Do you have the system development environment installed?

Comment: There is a relevant issue on Homebrew/homebrew-core: [macOS 13 (Ventura) and gcc-12](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/113968). From the discussions there, it seems like you have to install the *Command Line Tools for Xcode*.

Answer (score 1):

I've of course write #include <stdio.h>, the issue was with my GCC installation.
@kotatsuyaki was right, i ve just uninstall and re - install my GCC !

Answer (score -1):

You have an type error (no under score as first character), correct line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

From `_stdio.h` file

```
#ifndef _STDIO_H_
 #error error "Never use <secure/_stdio.h> directly; include <stdio.h> instead."
#endif
```

Comment: This answer does not address OP's problem. The error message containing `#include <_stdio.h>` comes from a header file inside GCC's implementation, not from OP's code.